# Return list item from search dialog to calling activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, listactivity

My application shall work the following way:

1. Activity #1 contains a text field (`EditText`) and a button.
2. If the user clicks the button a search dialog is opened via `onSearchRequested()`.
3. This calls the searchable activity #2 which extends `ListActivity`. It provides a list of items via `setListAdapter()`.
4. If the user clicks on a list item activity #2 shall pass the selected item's text back to activity #1 and display it in the text field.

Bullets #1-3 are clear and working. However I don't have any idea how to implement #4. I know about the possibility to use intents but it doesn't work if I use an intent after `onSearchRequested()`.

Thanks,
Robert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following solution is working fine for me:
http://blog.dpdearing.com/2011/05/getting-android-to-call-onactivityresult-after-onsearchrequested/

Answer (score 1):

I would simply send an intent with your selected item  as extra (`putExtra`) to your `activity#1` (since the search dialog is between `activity#1` and `activity#2`, you can not use `startActivityForResult` to post back the result to `activity#1`)

If the search dialog is in `activity#1`, then you can use `startActivityOnResult` (thanks dmon)

Comment: Hmmm... It seems to me that the dialog is *in* activity #1, so he *should* use `startActivityForResult()` and send the data back from activity #2 via the result intent.

Comment: if the dialog is in activity#1, then indeed, you are right,  he should use startActivityForResult. I pictured the dialog as an intermediary activity instead of a `Dialog`

Comment: @dmon  The search dialog is an activity of its own, i.e. it extends `ListActivity`.

Comment: Ah, sneaky! Then I guess you could create a "chain" of activity results, and propagate the result back "up"

Comment: you can but if your search activity doesnt need to know the result of `activity#2`, you can send the intent + extra to `activity#1`

Comment: @ccheneson I do understand your idea but somehow I got stuck while thinking about it ;-) I just can't figure out how to receive this intent in `activity #1` without using `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: If you send then the intent + extra from `activity#2` to `activity#1`, in `onCreate` or `onResume` of `activity#1`, you can do something like `if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) { ... here, if the key set as extra from activity#2 exists, you know that it was sent from activity#2 } `

Answer (score 0):

Simple, quick fix: store the data statically and do a check to retrieve it in Activity #1's onResume().